# How to avoid Same html code in Section tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I have 3 sections with the same html code inside , how can I avoid that , is there a way to just give them a piece of html code or as a code template by html,javascript...etc
Thanks , with regards .

```
    <section class="Movie-list-1"> 
       <h1> New movies </h1>
       <!--  10 divs here-->
    </section>
    <section class="Movie-list-2"> 
        <h1> 4k movies </h1>
     <!-- 10 divs here -->
    </section>
    <section class="Movie-list-3"> 
       <h1> New movies </h1>
     <!--  10 divs here -->
    </section>
```

Comment: Yes, You can do. Create simple one html template and use dynamically loading and binding. Could you add more concrete details about your problem.

Comment: so you mean that put this html code inside an html file then just use it ? but how it is not like css link stylesheet ..

Comment: yes of course bro , it is on above .

Comment: Yes it's possible. Probably the easiest way of doing it is using ["Web Components"](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Web_Components). Another - rather messy - option is by setting your template code into a tag's `.innerHTML`...

Comment: Yes , thanks man .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `<template>` and reuse it in a [custom element with slots](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_templates_and_slots):

```js
customElements.define('movie-list', class MovieList extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this
      .attachShadow({
        mode: 'open'
      })
      .appendChild(document.getElementById('movie-list').content.cloneNode(true));
  }
})
```

```html
<template id="movie-list">
<section class="movie-list">
  <h1><slot name="title">New movies</slot></h1>
  <slot name="divs"></slot>
</section>
</template>

<movie-list>
  <span slot="title">New Movies</span>
  <div slot="divs">
    <div>Foo</div>
    <div>Bar</div>
    <div>Baz</div>
  </div>
</movie-list>

<movie-list>
  <span slot="title">Top Movies</span>
  <div slot="divs">
    <div>Foo!!</div>
    <div>Bar?!</div>
    <div>Baz!?</div>
  </div>
</movie-list>
```

This is what it looks like in the DOM:

[image: Custom element movie-list: DOM]